# How to create promises with the new Breeze Angular Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, promise

I'm updating my angular/breeze application with the new breeze angular service ([link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service))

The documentation explains how to remove the Q.js file and so on. But now i'm stuck replacing this method:

```
primePromise = $q.all([getLookups(), getSpeakerPartials()])
    .then(extendMetadata)
    .then(success);

return primePromise;
```

or

```
$q.when();
```

how should i replace this piece of code with the new breeze angular service?

Comment: It looks like the Angular $q is a subset(?) of the full version of Q.js.  Have you looked at the documentation?  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q  I only see two methods available on the doc site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be worried about two different things.

1. How do I get a hold of `$q`
2. My `$q` is missing critical methods such as `.when` and `all`

You have to inject the `$q` service before you can use it as you are showing in your code snippet. Check the Angular documentation to see how to get it if you don't already know.

As for point #2, make sure you are running with Angular **v.1.2** and not an older version!

Before v.1.2, $q was extremely limited ... which is why I urged folks to stick to Q.js. For example, its promise only offered a `then` method.

[As of v.1.2](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q), a promise also offers `catch` and `finally` and `$q` has `all` and `when` methods.

Comment: Thx Ward. that's the info I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Ward, you might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301730/working-with-beforesaveentity-and-navigation-properties if you have time.

Comment: While that is an unrelated issue, I have answered it ... passionately.